# How to read and solve Webpack error in rails with Tailwind CSS?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, tailwind-css

I try to compile my rails app with tailwindcss for production and when I run `RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile` I have some web pack error here :

```
Compiling...
Compilation failed:
Hash: feaac03eae9fc5e6434d
Version: webpack 4.46.0
Time: 3691ms
Built at: 2021-05-03 8:34:24
 7 assets
Entrypoint application = js/application-719f586b83ab9096e6c4.js js/application-719f586b83ab9096e6c4.js.map
Entrypoint script/displayModal = js/script/displayModal-6f95a1a4d03fb01d89d2.js js/script/displayModal-6f95a1a4d03fb01d89d2.js.map
Entrypoint script/notify = js/script/notify-e556e1f24d4d09b43652.js js/script/notify-e556e1f24d4d09b43652.js.map
 [1] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 552 bytes {0} [built]
 [5] ./app/javascript/channels/index.js 205 bytes {0} [built]
 [6] ./app/javascript/channels sync _channel\.js$ 160 bytes {0} [built]
 [7] ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss 1.13 KiB {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
 [9] (webpack)/buildin/amd-options.js 80 bytes {0} [built]
[10] ./app/javascript/packs/script/displayModal.js 1.39 KiB {1} [built]
[11] ./app/javascript/packs/script/notify.js 405 bytes {2} [built]
[12] ./app/javascript/packs/application.js + 1 modules 25 KiB {0} [built]
     | ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 898 bytes [built]
     |     + 1 hidden module
    + 5 hidden modules

ERROR in ./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
    at Object.loader (/home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:38:24)
    at /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:316:20
    at /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 5:165-211

ERROR in ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: File to import not found or unreadable: @tailwindcss/base.
        on line 2 of /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss
>> @import "@tailwindcss/base";

   ^

    at /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:316:20
    at /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object.callback (/home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:73:7)
    at Object.done [as callback] (/home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:8069:18)
    at options.error (/home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:294:32)
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 5:133-165
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-1!node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-2!node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
       1 module
    
    ERROR in ./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-2!./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
        at Object.loader (/home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:38:24)
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-2!node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-3!app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
    [0] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-3!./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss 307 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
    
    ERROR in ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-3!./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    SassError: File to import not found or unreadable: @tailwindcss/base.
            on line 2 of /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss
    >> @import "@tailwindcss/base";
    
       ^
    

louis@Axolotl:~/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet$ RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile
yarn install v1.22.10
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.52s.
Compiling...
Compilation failed:
Hash: 604b9e914cd01865580d
Version: webpack 4.46.0
Time: 1644ms
Built at: 2021-05-03 8:34:41
 7 assets
Entrypoint application = js/application-8500d31757e42ce282b2.js js/application-8500d31757e42ce282b2.js.map
Entrypoint script/displayModal = js/script/displayModal-6f95a1a4d03fb01d89d2.js js/script/displayModal-6f95a1a4d03fb01d89d2.js.map
Entrypoint script/notify = js/script/notify-e556e1f24d4d09b43652.js js/script/notify-e556e1f24d4d09b43652.js.map
 [1] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 552 bytes {0} [built]
 [5] ./app/javascript/channels/index.js 205 bytes {0} [built]
 [6] ./app/javascript/channels sync _channel\.js$ 160 bytes {0} [built]
 [7] ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss 644 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
 [9] (webpack)/buildin/amd-options.js 80 bytes {0} [built]
[10] ./app/javascript/packs/script/displayModal.js 1.39 KiB {1} [built]
[11] ./app/javascript/packs/script/notify.js 405 bytes {2} [built]
[12] ./app/javascript/packs/application.js + 1 modules 25 KiB {0} [built]
     | ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 898 bytes [built]
     |     + 1 hidden module
    + 5 hidden modules

ERROR in ./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
    at Object.loader (/home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:38:24)
    at /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:316:20
    at /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 5:165-211

ERROR in ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
    at Object.loader (/home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:38:24)
    at /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:316:20
    at /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 5:133-165
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-1!node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-2!node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
       1 module
    
    ERROR in ./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-2!./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
        at Object.loader (/home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:38:24)
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-2!node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-3!app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
    [0] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-3!./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss 246 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
    
    ERROR in ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-3!./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
        at Object.loader (/home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:38:24)

louis@Axolotl:~/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet$ gem 'tailwindcss-rails', '~> 0.3.3'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command tailwindcss-rails,
louis@Axolotl:~/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet$ gem install tailwindcss-rails
Fetching tailwindcss-rails-0.3.3.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.7.0 directory.
louis@Axolotl:~/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet$ sudo gem install tailwindcss-rails
[sudo] Mot de passe de louis : 
Fetching tailwindcss-rails-0.3.3.gem
Successfully installed tailwindcss-rails-0.3.3
Parsing documentation for tailwindcss-rails-0.3.3
Installing ri documentation for tailwindcss-rails-0.3.3
Done installing documentation for tailwindcss-rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
louis@Axolotl:~/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet$ ./bin/rails tailwindcss:install
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'tailwindcss:install' (See the list of available tasks with `rails --tasks`)
/home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
/home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
louis@Axolotl:~/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet$ ./bin/bundle add tailwindcss-rails
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Resolving dependencies...
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 13.0.3
Following files may not be writable, so sudo is needed:
  /usr/local/bin
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/build_info
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/cache
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/doc
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/specifications
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.8
Using minitest 5.14.4
Using zeitwerk 2.4.2
Using builder 3.2.4
Using erubi 1.10.0
Using racc 1.5.2
Using crass 1.0.6
Using rack 2.2.3
Using nio4r 2.5.7
Using childprocess 3.0.0
Using marcel 1.0.1
Using regexp_property_values 1.0.0
Using method_source 1.0.0
Using ffi 1.15.0
Using json 2.5.1
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.4
Using bundler 2.2.16
Using tilt 2.0.10
Using semantic_range 3.0.0
Using spring 2.1.1
Using sqlite3 1.4.2
Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
Using i18n 1.8.10
Using thor 1.1.0
Using nokogiri 1.11.3 (x86_64-linux)
Using rack-test 1.1.0
Using msgpack 1.4.2
Using rack-mini-profiler 2.3.1
Using rack-proxy 0.6.5
Using puma 5.2.2
Using set 1.0.1
Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
Using mini_mime 1.0.2
Using turbolinks 5.2.1
Using xpath 3.2.0
Using bootsnap 1.7.3
Using mail 2.7.1
Using listen 3.5.1
Using byebug 11.1.3
Using regexp_parser 2.1.1
Using rbtree 0.4.4
Using sassc 2.4.0
Using sorted_set 1.0.3
Using loofah 2.9.1
Using character_set 1.4.1
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
Using js_regex 3.7.0
Using sprockets 4.0.2
Using rubyzip 2.3.0
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
Using selenium-webdriver 3.142.7
Using public_suffix 4.0.6
Using bindex 0.8.1
Using tzinfo 2.0.4
Using websocket-driver 0.7.3
Using activesupport 6.1.3.1
Using webdrivers 4.6.0
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using globalid 0.4.2
Using activemodel 6.1.3.1
Using activejob 6.1.3.1
Using jbuilder 2.11.2
Using activerecord 6.1.3.1
Using addressable 2.7.0
Using actionview 6.1.3.1
Using capybara 3.35.3
Using actionpack 6.1.3.1
Using actioncable 6.1.3.1
Using activestorage 6.1.3.1
Using actionmailer 6.1.3.1
Using actionmailbox 6.1.3.1
Using railties 6.1.3.1
Using actiontext 6.1.3.1
Using jquery-rails 4.4.0
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.2
Using webpacker 5.2.1
Using rails 6.1.3.1
Using web-console 4.1.0
Using rails_real_favicon 0.1.0
Using client_side_validations 18.0.0
Using tailwindcss-rails 0.3.3
Using sassc-rails 2.1.2
Using sass-rails 6.0.0
louis@Axolotl:~/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet$ ./bin/rails tailwindcss:install
Installing Tailwind CSS
         run  yarn add tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9 from "."
yarn add v1.22.10
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @babel/preset-react@7.13.13" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name@7.12.13" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@7.13.12" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-development@7.12.17" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-pure-annotations@7.12.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.12.13" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning " > @fullhuman/postcss-purgecss@4.0.3" has incorrect peer dependency "postcss@^8.0.0".
warning " > postcss-loader@5.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^5.0.0".
warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved 0 new dependencies.
Done in 3.14s.
File unchanged! The supplied flag value not found!  app/javascript/packs/application.js
Configuring Tailwind CSS
       exist  app/javascript/stylesheets
    conflict  app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss
Overwrite /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdhm] 
Overwrite /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdhm] y
       force  app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss
         run  npx tailwindcss init from "."
  
   @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat 2.1.2
  
    tailwind.config.js already exists.
  
      insert  postcss.config.js
Add Tailwindcss include tags in application layout
      insert  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
louis@Axolotl:~/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet$ RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile
yarn install v1.22.10
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @babel/preset-react@7.13.13" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name@7.12.13" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@7.13.12" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-development@7.12.17" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-pure-annotations@7.12.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.12.13" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning " > @fullhuman/postcss-purgecss@4.0.3" has incorrect peer dependency "postcss@^8.0.0".
warning " > postcss-loader@5.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^5.0.0".
warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 2.44s.
I, [2021-05-03T08:43:48.622679 #7400]  INFO -- : Writing /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/public/assets/inter-font-a789ddd81e85c482dcbaec4865a1b97cdf87e8185ac9ab08da0f7d37f372cad7.css
I, [2021-05-03T08:43:48.623125 #7400]  INFO -- : Writing /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/public/assets/inter-font-a789ddd81e85c482dcbaec4865a1b97cdf87e8185ac9ab08da0f7d37f372cad7.css.gz
I, [2021-05-03T08:43:48.623370 #7400]  INFO -- : Writing /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/public/assets/Inter-italic.extra.var-cc59cf4b324781109d703309fc7d8814b6ba74dd2822a3c029715da8cb98ea57.woff2
I, [2021-05-03T08:43:48.623801 #7400]  INFO -- : Writing /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/public/assets/Inter-italic.alternates.var-cc59cf4b324781109d703309fc7d8814b6ba74dd2822a3c029715da8cb98ea57.woff2
I, [2021-05-03T08:43:48.624736 #7400]  INFO -- : Writing /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/public/assets/Inter-italic.symbols.var-59f27012284f5e97bbff303eb599ca98f29629a1c0fe7352bcc15b27d1dcd937.woff2
I, [2021-05-03T08:43:48.625941 #7400]  INFO -- : Writing /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/public/assets/Inter-italic.cyrillic.var-a31159d5ce68b317b19edc7ee7f1f3ffdd5316ee899945b502406abda313afa2.woff2
I, [2021-05-03T08:43:48.626774 #7400]  INFO -- : Writing /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/public/assets/Inter-italic.greek.var-77ec12f9397b88a29c16c05f2db87d9c0d0c2b157f1980271fed020f00b35321.woff2
I, [2021-05-03T08:43:48.627914 #7400]  INFO -- : Writing /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/public/assets/Inter-italic.vietnamese.var-b5dc5b6490ba49e8193315ff62c8e90551102055440f084a6e982e5eab8e589a.woff2
I, [2021-05-03T08:43:48.629039 #7400]  INFO -- : Writing /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/public/assets/Inter-italic.latin-ext.var-802705fb8496b82eda3f410c7e70a35c9407ba98b97cc5d9754db82750466fad.woff2
I, [2021-05-03T08:43:48.630139 #7400]  INFO -- : Writing /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/public/assets/Inter-italic.latin.var-cbfc0334f8cfad4727431982cd32c32f7daf6e73f0ab6f759ec3dc757c1c6bf7.woff2
I, [2021-05-03T08:43:48.631355 #7400]  INFO -- : Writing /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/public/assets/Inter-roman.extra.var-29781a209d7978155bf343eb1653779269965fa4a43d504b1fb361ab20e8487b.woff2
I, [2021-05-03T08:43:48.631898 #7400]  INFO -- : Writing /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/public/assets/Inter-roman.alternates.var-29781a209d7978155bf343eb1653779269965fa4a43d504b1fb361ab20e8487b.woff2
I, [2021-05-03T08:43:48.632638 #7400]  INFO -- : Writing /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/public/assets/Inter-roman.symbols.var-847d2a436a03ba1fbd4b750915db031a12a713befe0dcd79e8f39bf6a6e1a647.woff2
I, [2021-05-03T08:43:48.633120 #7400]  INFO -- : Writing /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/public/assets/Inter-roman.cyrillic.var-8aa524d3da3b8fd4a03ff2d0d41ea50520113fb2e8ae57c15079dabea44b3529.woff2
I, [2021-05-03T08:43:48.634218 #7400]  INFO -- : Writing /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/public/assets/Inter-roman.greek.var-1134a39060691474b0f57b2de5e09977a31a8c06df90960b982314f58a5b4c63.woff2
I, [2021-05-03T08:43:48.634604 #7400]  INFO -- : Writing /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/public/assets/Inter-roman.vietnamese.var-a10e650090dc30250de0db440654c9bf29a843b233ee95a699b008bab0a6d498.woff2
I, [2021-05-03T08:43:48.635094 #7400]  INFO -- : Writing /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/public/assets/Inter-roman.latin-ext.var-46bc23ba7e33ea447579cd95b95f34665d7560377065b72f3a77df8bca4b0e5c.woff2
I, [2021-05-03T08:43:48.635536 #7400]  INFO -- : Writing /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/public/assets/Inter-roman.latin.var-4b87a3d384ea557b10afa9570b753eda868b12b5e51eea0977ffa6e641998f6a.woff2
I, [2021-05-03T08:43:48.649498 #7400]  INFO -- : Writing /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/public/assets/tailwind-d11623fa43b89ebbd73fc802278c1b4dbe024deb897ae4d9843d7568f9380779.css
I, [2021-05-03T08:43:48.649676 #7400]  INFO -- : Writing /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/public/assets/tailwind-d11623fa43b89ebbd73fc802278c1b4dbe024deb897ae4d9843d7568f9380779.css.gz
Compiling...
Compilation failed:
Hash: 604b9e914cd01865580d
Version: webpack 4.46.0
Time: 1604ms
Built at: 2021-05-03 8:43:51
 7 assets
Entrypoint application = js/application-8500d31757e42ce282b2.js js/application-8500d31757e42ce282b2.js.map
Entrypoint script/displayModal = js/script/displayModal-6f95a1a4d03fb01d89d2.js js/script/displayModal-6f95a1a4d03fb01d89d2.js.map
Entrypoint script/notify = js/script/notify-e556e1f24d4d09b43652.js js/script/notify-e556e1f24d4d09b43652.js.map
 [1] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 552 bytes {0} [built]
 [5] ./app/javascript/channels/index.js 205 bytes {0} [built]
 [6] ./app/javascript/channels sync _channel\.js$ 160 bytes {0} [built]
 [7] ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss 644 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
 [9] (webpack)/buildin/amd-options.js 80 bytes {0} [built]
[10] ./app/javascript/packs/script/displayModal.js 1.39 KiB {1} [built]
[11] ./app/javascript/packs/script/notify.js 405 bytes {2} [built]
[12] ./app/javascript/packs/application.js + 1 modules 25 KiB {0} [built]
     | ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 898 bytes [built]
     |     + 1 hidden module
    + 5 hidden modules

ERROR in ./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
    at Object.loader (/home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:38:24)
    at /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:316:20
    at /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 5:165-211

ERROR in ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
    at Object.loader (/home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:38:24)
    at /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:316:20
    at /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 5:133-165
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-1!node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-2!node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
       1 module
    
    ERROR in ./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-2!./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
        at Object.loader (/home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:38:24)
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-2!node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-3!app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
    [0] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-3!./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss 246 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
    
    ERROR in ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-3!./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
        at Object.loader (/home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:38:24)
```

I don't know how to read it because the error always go to some node module and not into some file in my app...

Here is the postcss.conf file :

```js
// postcss.config.js
let environment = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss')('./app/javascript/stylesheets/tailwind.config.js'),
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
    require('postcss-preset-env')({
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: 'no-2009'
      },
      stage: 3
    })
  ]
};

if (process.env.RAILS_ENV === 'production') {
  environment.plugins.push(
      require('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss')({
        content: [
          './app/**/.html.erb',
          './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
          './app/javascript/**/*.js',
          './app/javascript/**/*.vue',
          './app/javascript/**/*.jsx',
        ],
        defaultExtractor: (content) => content.match(/[A-Za-z0-9-_:/]+/g) || []
      })
  )
}

module.exports = environment;
```

here is my package.json :

```json
{
  "name": "twity-mine-r",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "@client-side-validations/client-side-validations": "^0.1.5",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
    "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^4.0.3",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "postcss": "^7",
    "postcss-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

here is the head of my application.js

```js
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"
import "stylesheets/application"
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all"
import "jquery"
Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()
```

And the head of my application.scss :

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

Comment: Focus on this error `PostCSS plugin postcss-purgecss requires PostCSS 8.`. My guess is that you didn't remove node_modules when you kept trying and that you didn't remove package-lock.json or yarn.lock

Comment: I have added postcss-loader and It works but for the first error only :/
So the rest of the error is still there. I have edited my question with the new trace

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have to use a PostCSS 7 Compatibility build with Rails as Webpacker does not play nice with PostCSS 8.

```
yarn add tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

I would remove the PostCSS 8 package and autoprefixer and go with these here.

The other thing you could do is use the new rubygem that David Heinemeier Hansson just recently released: [tailwindcss-rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/tailwindcss-rails)

The only caveat with the new gem is that you will be limited in customization if you need to use @apply for example. Otherwise, this is great way to bring Tailwind through the asset pipeline and have all the other configuration handled for you.

Comment: I have tried but I continue to have some error with font awesome and css-loader. I have updated my thread with a new error and stack trace

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling webpacker? A lot of times, problems like that can be cleared up by doing that.